# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.DS_Store'

Tags: python, shell, terminal, nlp, nltk

I am working on implementing a program that will give me the result for the Positional inverted index of an xml file.
First I need to change the type of document number from string to int in order to use it later on.

Some of my code is the following:

```
def index(document_directory, dictionary_file, postings_file):
    # preprocess docID list

        docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir(document_directory)]
        docID_list.sort()
        stemmer = PorterStemmer()
        stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
        # stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        docs_indexed = 0    # counter for the number of docs indexed
        dictionary = {}     # key: term, value: docIDs containing term (incudes repeats)
            # for each document in corpus
        for docID in docID_list:
                if (LIMIT and docs_indexed == LIMIT): break
.
.
.
.
.
            # open files for writing   
        dict_file = codecs.open(dictionary_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        post_file = open(postings_file, 'wb')
.
.
.
.
            # close files
        dict_file.close()
        post_file.close()    
.
.
.
.

"""
prints the proper command usage
"""
def print_usage():
    print ("usage: " + sys.argv[0] + "-i directory-of-documents -d dictionary-file -p postings-file")

.
.
.
if (RECORD_TIME): start = timeit.default_timer()                              # start time
index(document_directory, dictionary_file, postings_file)   # call the indexer
if (RECORD_TIME): stop = timeit.default_timer()                               # stop time
if (RECORD_TIME): print ('Indexing time:' + str(stop - start))                # print time taken
```

Now when I run it using the command:

> $ python def_ind.py -i "./index/" -d "output1111.txt" -p "output222.txt"

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "def_ind.py", line 161, in <module>
    index(document_directory, dictionary_file, postings_file)   # call the indexer
  File "def_ind.py", line 36, in index
    docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir(document_directory)]
  File "def_ind.py", line 36, in <listcomp>
    docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir(document_directory)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.DS_Store'
```

I understand that there is a string that can't be int, but I didn't know
how?
What am supposed to do in here?

I am trying to get output that will check each word how many times appeared in each document number and in which line.
for example:(document number: line number where the word found)

```
  and:
    2: 5,7
    5: 5

flower:
    1: 8
    2: 4,6,8
    3: 6
    4: 6
    5: 6
```

snapshot from my xml file:

```
    <DOCNO>1</DOCNO>
    <PROFILE>_AN-BENBQAD8FT</PROFILE>
    <DATE>910514
    </DATE>
    <HEADLINE>
    FT  14 MAY 91 / (CORRECTED) Jubilee of a jet that did what it was designed
    to do
    </HEADLINE>
    <TEXT>
       words, words, words
    </TEXT>
    <PUB>The Financial Times
    </PUB>
    <PAGE>
    London Page 7 Photograph (Omitted).
    </PAGE>
    </DOC>`
```

I am using python 3.7.

Note: I found many questions with the same error but non of them suited my situation.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding  your question, but you are listing the files in a directory and casting the names to int and wonder why it throws an exception?

Comment: I am trying to take the document number from the xml file. What wrong did I make? am new to python tho.

Comment: Please reduce your code to what is essential to the question.

Comment: ok. I added an example of my xml file

Answer (score 0):

The function [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns names of files in that particular directory.

AS your error says, you are trying to cast these names to integers. That is the cause of your error, in this line:

```
docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir(document_directory)]
```

The code you pasted is a mess (maybe its just wrong indentation after pasting to StackOverflow); I cannot understand what you are trying to acomplish there. As far as I can see, you never actually use the values of the list `docID_list`, you just iterate over it. So why are you even casting the values to `int`?